# Merge Backbone collection without changing order

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have a backbone collection that represents N photos. Initially I have few (lets say X) photos out of those N in my collection.

My collection then fetches all N photos from service. I can just reset my collection with these N but the problem is that, existing X has some additional metadata and I don't want to lose it. So I want to merge these N photos in my existing collection. How do I do that?

I tried using collection.add(N photos) but what that does is it keeps X photos as it is, and then adds remaining (N-X) at the end. I want keep the ordering of N photos as returned by service, and kind of merge these existing ones into the N photos.

Comment: So you have `X`, get `N` from the server, `N` has (or may have) things that are already in `X`, and you want to merge the extra attributes from `X` into the corresponding models in `N` without disturbing the order of things in `N`. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the collection's `comparator` for this:

> **comparator** `collection.comparator`
>
> By default there is no **comparator** for a collection. If you define a comparator, it will be used to maintain the collection in sorted order. This means that as models are added, they are inserted at the correct index in `collection.models`.

So all you need to do is make sure your collection has a `comparator` that knows the order of things in `N` before you call `add`. A rough and ugly proof of concept would look like this:

```
// `incoming` is the new data, `c` is the collection.
for(var i = 0, rev = { }; i < incoming.length; ++i)
    rev[incoming[i].id] = i;
c.comparator = function(m) {
    return rev[m.id];
};
c.add(incoming);
```

A real version would, presumably, be wrapped up inside your collection.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/dCZbv/